# AssertionError when using self-defined nested list in Pyspc

Tags: python-3.x, spc

I installed pyspc and run on Jupyter Notebook successfully when using original samples.
But when I tried introducing a self defined nested list and an error message showed up.
pyspc library: https://github.com/carlosqsilva/pyspc

```
from pyspc import*
import numpy
abc=[[2,3,4],[4,5.6],[1,4,5],[3,4,4],[4,5,6]]
a=spc(abc)+xbar_rbar()+rules()+rbar()
print(a)
```

[error message for AssertionError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPxrq.jpg)

Thank you for advise where went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You have not posted the entire error trace. Most likely, the error is coming from the fact that your `a` object does not have a __repr__ function

Comment: Hi Mortz, Thank you and would you mind taking a look over the link "error message for AssertionError" and comment more where I can look for resolution.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea about the SPC library. What does your `a = spc(abc) + ...` assignment do? What kind of an object is a? Is it printable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the data you have accidentally used the `.` instead of `,` for value `[4,5.6]`, second element of the list.

Here is the corrected data

```
abc=[[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[1,4,5],[3,4,4],[4,5,6]]
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi MaNKur, Thank you for your careful check, it's really a negligence and mistake and I fix it and it works now!